# R: ne-name factor-values in data.frame

Tags: r, class, integer, dataframe, rename

**EDITED**

I have a `data.frame` [integer_disc] that consists of `integer` variables (with values 1,2,3). The dataframe has about 120 columns and 54,000 rows. Below is a snipped

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  Col 4 [up to Col 120]
1      2      1     1 
3      1      2     1
2      2      2     2
1      3      3     1
```

(**EDIT**: As in the snippet above, it is indeed possible that some columns only have two of the three values. I checked it with `str`. **edit end**)

I want to re-name those into "low", "medium", and "high". Probably I have to turn them into `factor` values before? That I would do via

```
integers_factor <- lapply(integer_disc, function(x) as.factor(x))
```

Then I read how re-naming is done here ([change name of specific levels in factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821985/change-name-of-specific-levels-in-factor)), but the difference is that I need to re-name all columns, giving output like this:

```
Col1     Col2       Col3       Col 4 [up to Col 120]
low      medium      low       low
high     low         medium    low
medium   medium      medium    medium        
low      high        high      low
```

I also tried the `cut` function but this does not seem to work either (neither with `integer` nor `factor` values.

```
integer_disc_labelled <- cut(integers_factor, breaks=c(1,2,3), labels=c("low","medium","high"))
```

(Probably I would need another data `class` here again!?)

Probably there is an easy way to re-name the values with a specified function that I am not aware of?

Thanks a lot for every idea!

Comment: Does every column have all the levels of the factor or some columns can have only two or one level?

Comment: ah, sorry for being imprecise again. I edited my question, since it seems important that some only have 2 levels...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** way: 
Using `ifelse` statements:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2   Col3  
1      2      1
3      1      2
2      2      2
1      3      3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[] <- lapply(df, function(col) ifelse(col == 1, "low", 
                                 ifelse(col == 2, "med", "high")))

> df
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1  low  med  low
2 high  low  med
3  med  med  med
4  low  high high
```

**Second** way:
Using `factor`'s `labels` argument:
(changed the last value of Col2 for demo where one column doesn't contain all values):

```
df <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2   Col3  
1      2      1
3      1      2
2      2      2
1      2      3", 
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df[] <- lapply(df, factor, 
                 levels = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 labels = c("low", "med", "high"))
> df
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1  low  med  low
2 high  low  med
3  med  med  med
4  low  med high

> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Col1: Factor w/ 3 levels "low","med","high": 1 3 2 1
 $ Col2: Factor w/ 3 levels "low","med","high": 2 1 2 2
 $ Col3: Factor w/ 3 levels "low","med","high": 1 2 2 3
```

I edited my examples based on helpful comments by @agenis and @Roland - thanks!
The neat trick with the brackets makes sure that the original object class and structure are preserved - I learnt it from Hadley's [Subassignment](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subassignment) chapter.

Comment: this works only if each column has all levels of the factor. If one is missing, it gives an error.

Comment: If you use the `labels` argument you should always use the `levels` argument too.

Comment: so does it do the trick to first separate the `data.frame` into two separate ones which have either only 2 or only 3 values?

Comment: jap, @PeterDee, your edit did the trick! Thanks for the help!

Comment: nice, @PeterDee. I didn't know the "bracket trick". How does it work?

Comment: Thanks all. @agenis - see my last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try ('df' from @PeterDee's post)

```
df[] <- c('low', 'med', 'high')[as.matrix(df)]
df
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1  low  med  low
#2 high  low  med
#3  med  med  med
#4  low high high
```

Answer (score 0):

Another related approach would be to use `tidyr`'s `gather` function to move all of the variables to a single column, then apply the factor conversion to the gathered column, then use the `spread` function to spread back to the original columns.